# How to Find the View We Came From (Built-In Way) in C# ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In `ASP.NET MVC 5`, Suppose we have an `Action` and we want to have different re-directions depend on which `View` calls the `Action`:

```
if (comingFromView1) {
    return RedirectToAction("View1", "SomeController");     
} else if (comingFromView2) {
    return RedirectToAction("View2", "SomeController");     
} //...and so on
```

Is there any built-in way to distinguish which `View` call the `Action`? We could do something by using `ViewBag.Caller = "View1"` in the `View` before calling the `Actions` to distinguish one `View` from another, for example. But if we have many `Views`, it would be preferred if there is a built-in ready way to do it.

Comment: `Request.UrlReferrer` will give you the page you navigated from.

Comment: @StephenMuecke hei, thanks! That is exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score -2):

```
Uri urlOrigen = Request.UrlReferrer;

bool fromAnuncio = urlOrigen.ToString().Contains("Anuncio/ListAction");

if(fromAnuncio) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You should explain how this answers the question, along with properly formatting your code.